# Rails query caching is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I use redis_store for caching queries.In development log i couldn't see the cached queries,It again hits the database and gets the records,But in my redis console i can see the keys which i have used to cache the queries.I tested in rails console to read the queries using keys.I could get the cached queries.Help me to solve this.

In my model

```
Category = Rails.cache.fetch("category") {Category.select(:foo).unique}
```

In redis

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
"category"
```

In rails console

```
Rails.cache.read("category")
```

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily add this line to `/config/environments/development.rb`

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

Don't forget to delete it when you're done!

Comment: Yeah,It was already true.I use caching action in that same app,But it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't cache in development, so what @megas says is true, you should rather have a test to check if caching works as it should and in your test environment you could change your `config.action_controller.perform_caching` to true.